# Integrate 3 different mvc website projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have 3 different MVC 5 websites projects developed separately by 3 different programmers. 
the 3 projects share the same database , each application uses different tables of course.
the projects share the users database to allow/deny access to different features.

How can integrate those 3 projects into one project? Should i use one solution and 3 different class libraries and one website project?
I am not sure to organize this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is, it depends. A few questions come to mind that would help me decide how to proceed:

- Is there any overlap beyond the users table?
- If not, would I not be better served by splitting the database up
  into one database per distinct application and creating a common web
  service for user management?
- Does each MVC application have a distinct job? If so, what am I gaining by combining them?

Basically what I'm saying is, just because they share a common database, doesn't mean they necessarily should be one application.

Comment: You are absolutely right, they 3 applications shared a lot tables and there's some overlapping

Comment: My next consideration then would be, do the overlapping tables involve shared business logic? Can the shared logic be pushed into a common web service accessible by all three projects? Would that eliminate the shared usage? Combining three distinct apps with separate purposes raises hairs on the back of my neck, so I would only do so with caution and very good reason. :)

Comment: Here's my scenario and you can tell me what do you think:
The three applications are : CRM, LMS and A task scheduler.
the overlapping functionality: they share the same users database for authentication and role assignment. the same website interface so the user can access the 3 systems

Comment: Those sound like three distinct apps to me. I'd push all common functionality to web services with their own databases and re-factor the common database to an individual database for each application which only has the tables it needs to do its job. Should be much easier than trying to glue the apps together and more maintainable as it follows the S in SOLID: single responsibility. That being said, I've never seen your schema, databases, apps, users, etc, so I'd take whatever anyone here has to say with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thank you so much Casey for your answers. I think it's time for me to step up and spend more time on the architecture and the design part. Is there some books or references you can recommend. I am interested in the MVC design Pattern. I am not asking for MVC resources here but more on how to architecture your application and what are the best practices and things to consider

Comment: You're quite welcome. As for resources, [Head First's Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596007124) book helped me. There's also the classic and arguably mandatory for all developers serious about good design, [Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented-ebook/dp/B000SEIBB8).

Comment: Now i have a different problem:


I copied the controllers and models from my existing project to a new one , but for some reason i got this error message: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Email'. Invalid column name 'EmailConfirmed'. Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber'. Invalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'. Invalid column name 'TwoFactorEnabled'. Invalid column name 'LockoutEndDateUtc'. Invalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'. Invalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'. I think it's the schema of the Identitymodel and my model.

How to fix this ?

Comment: Sounds like your EDMX model is out of sync with your database model.

Comment: I agree with you, but how to fix it? i tried add-migration then update-database but no luck

Comment: Should probably ask another question on StackOverlow with the pertinent details of the error (code, schema, etc).

Comment: here's the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812539/edmx-model-is-out-of-sync-with-my-database-model

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a solution and adding each project to that solution. As long as the web.configs put to said databases and all of your references are correct, the project should build fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on a .Net project where there were over ten projects in one solution. So I think creating one solution is a great start, and you could have the 3 projects read the DB connection string from the central web.config file. And in some cases, one project needs a reference to another one, in which case the appropriate DLL's get added as a Reference in the project which accesses that DLL.