# EDMX model is out of sync with my database model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using code first approach, but I am not sure why I am having this issue.
Here's a part of my AccountViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

and here's the error message:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Email'.
Invalid column name 'EmailConfirmed'.
Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber'.
Invalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'.
Invalid column name 'TwoFactorEnabled'.
Invalid column name 'LockoutEndDateUtc'.
Invalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'.
Invalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'.
Invalid column name 'Email'.
Invalid column name 'EmailConfirmed'.
Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber'.
Invalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'.
Invalid column name 'TwoFactorEnabled'.
Invalid column name 'LockoutEndDateUtc'.
Invalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'.
Invalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'.
Invalid column name 'UserId'.
Invalid column name 'UserId'.
Invalid column name 'Email'.
Invalid column name 'EmailConfirmed'.
Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber'.
Invalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'.
Invalid column name 'TwoFactorEnabled'.
Invalid column name 'LockoutEndDateUtc'.
Invalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'.
Invalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'.
Line 102:     if (ModelState.IsValid)
Line 103:     {
Line 104:        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
Line 105:        if (user != null)
Line 106:        {
```

Please help me understand why I am getting this error?

Comment: When do you get this error, what are you trying to do?

Comment: to access the users account database it's the username/password check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the answer for my problem.
It's the updated package: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework from version 1 to version 2.

apparently the new version has new database attributes that needs to be mapped. 
More on this issue: [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/updating-asp-net-applications-from-asp-net-identity-1-0-to-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx)