# Invalid column name 'Discriminator'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an existing `ASP NET MVC 5` that has uses `AppUsers` database to authenticate users.   It been working for over a year.

Today, I created a new demo ASP MVC 5 application and set the `[Authorize]` tag to a specific `[AspNetRoles]` role.   I also have the "AppUsers" `connectionString` set up in the new application `web.config` file.   It is identical connection as the first existing application

When I try to login using the new application, I get the error shown below.   I assumed that I can use the "AppUsers" DB to authenticate users using different applications.   Any suggestion on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.   I searched the web, but this error seems to have many different causes, none I have seen seems to explain my issue.

Thank you 
Mike

> Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
>       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> ```
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
>
> Source Error:
>
>
> Line 46:             if (ModelState.IsValid)
> Line 47:             {
> Line 48:                 var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
> Line 49:                 if (user != null)
> Line 50:                 {
>
>
> Source File: c:\Users\204026705\Documents\MyApps\!!!!VSnet\TestPublishToNewServer\TestPublishToNewServer\Controllers\AccountController.cs
> ```
>
> Line: 48
>
> ```
> Stack Trace:
>
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.]
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> ```
>
> +1767866
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5352418
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +365
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds) +1406
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) +177
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +53
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +134
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +41
>          System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
>          System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.b__c(DbCommand
>   t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +66
>          System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +138
>          System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +475
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +239
>          System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +97
>
> ```
> [EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for
> ```
>
> details.]
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +181
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +1282
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
>   +184
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +448
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>   +270
>          System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +251
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) +645
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   +68
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +68
>          System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +164
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1(IEnumerable`1
>   sequence) +83
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot) +107
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression) +197
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression) +155
>          System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +251
>          Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1.FindByNameAsync(String
>   userName) +1175
>          Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindByNameAsync>d__d.MoveNext() +231
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
>          Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__15.MoveNext() +540
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
>          TestPublishToNewServer.Controllers.<Login>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\Users\204026705\Documents\MyApps\!!!!VSnet\TestPublishToNewServer\TestPublishToNewServer\Controllers\AccountController.cs:48
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
>          lambda_method(Closure , Task ) +64
>          System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task)
>   +64
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +114
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass34.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__33(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +65
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +47
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c()
>   +117
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e()
>   +323
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +47
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +50
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19()
>   +72
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +185
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +40
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +70
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +62
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +70
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +38
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9514928
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24816251/1837329

Comment: Hi Alundra ... You suggestion gave me a hint to follow ... thank you.   What I did after I read your note is I did a full update of all nuget packages (Update All).   This did the trick for me as I've already done the migration ~ few months ago when I upgraded the EF.

Comment: Great. It drove me crazy at the time. Don't forget to vote up the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to do a ful update of all nuget packages.   In my case, I created new project, updated the EF from nuget, implemented connecting string changes to set up the Authorization using "AppUsers" DB to authenticate users.

This ran me into the subject error.

Alundra suggested a migration.   However, I have already done a migration in the past.   The next logical step was to update nuget packages.   This solved the problem.   I suspect that the culprit was updating EF only at the beginning.

Thank
Mike